# sssd got killed due to segfault in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, crash, sssd

```
SSSD.LOG
--------------
(Sun Jun 14 20:23:53 2020) [sssd] [mt_svc_sigkill] (0x0010): [pam][13305] is not responding to SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
(Sun Jun 14 20:29:34 2020) [sssd] [monitor_restart_service] (0x0010): Process [nss], definitely stopped!
```

```
apport.log:
--------------
ERROR: apport (pid 623) Sun Jun 14 20:25:21 2020: Unhandled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apport/apport", line 515, in <module>
    get_pid_info(pid)
  File "/usr/share/apport/apport", line 62, in get_pid_info
    proc_pid_fd = os.open('/proc/%s' % pid, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_PATH | os.O_DIRECTORY)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/13305'
ERROR: apport (pid 623) Sun Jun 14 20:25:21 2020: pid: 623, uid: 0, gid: 0, euid: 0, egid: 0
ERROR: apport (pid 623) Sun Jun 14 20:25:21 2020: environment: environ({})
root@gamma13:/var/log# ps -fp 13305
UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
```

```
syslog
--------------
Jun 14 20:20:32 gamma13 sssd[be[myorg]]: Starting up
Jun 14 20:22:06 gamma13 kernel: [2543859.316724] sssd_pam[13305]: segfault at a4 ip 00007f0f77329989 sp 00007fff35844480 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.14.6[7f0f772ff000+4b000]
Jun 14 20:22:06 gamma13 sssd[be[myorg]]: Starting up
Jun 14 20:22:53 gamma13 sssd: Killing service [pam], not responding to pings!
Jun 14 20:23:53 gamma13 sssd: [pam][13305] is not responding to SIGTERM. Sending SIGKILL.
Jun 14 20:23:58 gamma13 sssd[pam]: Starting up
Jun 14 20:24:27 gamma13 smtpd[1732]: smtp-in: session 689f0b74a7b74828: connection from host gamma13.internal.myorg.com.internal.myorg.com [local] established
Jun 14 20:25:01 gamma13 CRON[1041]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 14 20:25:01 gamma13 CRON[1042]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/icsisnap /var/lib/icsisnap)
Jun 14 20:27:57 gamma13 sssd[be[myorg]]: Starting up
Jun 14 20:27:58 gamma13 systemd[1]: Started Session 16859 of user kamals.
Jun 14 20:29:18 gamma13 sssd[be[myorg]]: Starting up
Jun 14 20:29:28 gamma13 sssd[nss]: Starting up
Jun 14 20:29:30 gamma13 sssd[nss]: Starting up
Jun 14 20:29:37 gamma13 sssd[nss]: Starting up
Jun 14 20:29:37 gamma13 sssd: Exiting the SSSD. Could not restart critical service [nss].
Jun 14 20:29:44 gamma13 sssd[be[myorg]]: Shutting down
Jun 14 20:29:44 gamma13 sssd[pam]: Shutting down
```

[Another server also had encountered with the same issue, `sssd` got killed by logging this below,

```
Jun 9 21:12:52 grid kernel: [5088481.338650] rpcmgr[1409]: segfault at 7fa5541c1d13 ip 00007fa5dcb5be8f sp 00007fa5d35ccc80 error 4 in libpthread-2.23.so[7fa5dcb54000+18000]

]
```

```
kamals@gamma13:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-178-generic
kamals@gamma13:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
```

Hi, the `sssd` got killed for second time with `segfault`, the above log is the latest `sssd death`.

Please help me how to fix this issue. Thank you